How to Style Acronyms in Glossaries Package
I would be very appreciative if someone is able to please help in styling the output of the acronyms for the glossaries package. If there are also tutorials for beginners that outline the principles, I would be really keen to learn. The look I after is as follows (the gray line and the additional white space)

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,table]{article}

\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\usepackage[acronyms, toc, nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossaries
    
\end{document}

